# Camel Artemis Connection Pool not JMS 2.0 Compliant

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-artemis

I am trying to get Camel to play nicely with Artemis and connection pools. I am using the following tech stack.

- Springboot: 2.3.1.RELEASE
- Camel: 3.4.1

The connection pool is created using the following dependencies:

- org.messaginghub.pooled-jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory
- org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory

I am still seeing the message during startup:

```
o.m.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory  : JMS ConnectionFactory on classpath is not a JMS 2.0+ version
```

The connection factory is from the Artemis code base so not sure why the JmsPoolConnectionFactory is saying this.

See my code below:

```
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration;
import org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import javax.jms.JMSException;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {


    private ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    @Bean
    public JmsComponent jms() throws JMSException {
        // Create the connectionfactory which will be used to connect to Artemis
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL("(tcp://artemo-activemq-artemis-master-0.artemo-activemq-artemis-master.default.svc.cluster.local:61616,tcp://artemo-activemq-artemis-master-1.artemo-activemq-artemis-master.default.svc.cluster.local:61616)");
        connectionFactory.setUseTopologyForLoadBalancing(true);
        connectionFactory.setUser("artemis");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("artemis");
        connectionFactory.setConsumerWindowSize(8388608);



        JmsPoolConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new JmsPoolConnectionFactory();
        pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(16);
        pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();
        jmsConfiguration.setConcurrentConsumers(16);
        jmsConfiguration.setArtemisStreamingEnabled(true);
        jmsConfiguration.setTransacted(true);

        jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(pooledConnectionFactory);

        // Create the Camel JMS component and wire it to our Artemis connectionfactory
        JmsComponent jms = new JmsComponent();
        jms.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);


        return jms;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is Artemis version ? It should work since the createContext(int sessionMode) exists on ActiveMQConnectionFactory and this is what JmsPoolConnectionFactory is looking for by reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the message here is referring to the `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` *interface* on the classpath, not the ActiveMQ Artemis implementation of `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory`. Therefore, you should check to see what version JMS API is on the classpath. This is the dependency that ActiveMQ Artemis uses:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
   <artifactId>geronimo-jms_2.0_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yeah I did a bit of digging and seems like the JMS component in Camel is not JMS2 compatible I switched over to the SJMS2 component which is JMS 2 compatible. This component has its own connection pooling so dont need the messaging hub connection pool either which does simplify dependencies a bit.  It also seems to work better with Artemis. When using JMS 1.0 clients some the cluster features was not working as expected.